# Exhibit "Attribute Table" Field values when mouse hovers on top of a feature in Shapefile in QGIS2.8?

Tags: attribute-table, line, qgis-2.8

I am drawing a line to represent a Fibre Cable. I would like to see the Attribute Table of this line pop up the field values assigned to this line representing a Fibre Cable (Aerial or Underground).

Comment: Are you trying to do this in code, or looking for some configuration option. Do you want to edit the table, or just show some values for that specific linestring?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for what ArcMap knows as MapTips.

Comment: Please read "I am drawing a line...." instead of "I drawing a line..."